# Why did VNQ not pay a dividend in March 2021?

Tags: united-states, vanguard, reit

I am trying to research Dividend on REITS and I was surprised to see [vanguard](https://investor.vanguard.com/etf/profile/distributions/vnq) has no dividend for its VNQ ETF. Is it the first time or may it be due to COVID?

Note: When I look at [yahoo](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VNQ), I see, dates for dividend as (for March quarter):

- March 10, 2020
- Mar 28, 2019
- Mar 26, 2018

So I was expecting it to be near 2nd week of March rather than 3rd or 4th week. Is there any **standard (or rule**) that ETF companies need to follow for dividends or it is arbitrary?

Comment: *Apparently Vanguard likes to keep their ETF ex-dividend and distribution dates a secret until just a couple days before the event* https://sixfigureinvesting.com/2011/01/ex-dividend-pay-dates-vfh-vnq-vug-voo/

Comment: Unless they twiddle their thumbs for several days every quarter, transactions are still happening, so how could anyone publish the results earlier? Unless they move all their March gains into the June dividends. I rather know the exact amount a bit later but get the dividend this quarter.

Comment: @bernhard-döbler thanks, is there any rule/standard that etf companies need to follow ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where I live, it is still March, for several more days, and I am pretty sure there will be a dividend announcement.
If you look at the last three quarters, and not just VNQ but many other Vanguard ETFs, they have moved *all* their pay-out dates to the *30th*, so there are some more days left until the publishing is due.

Update 2020-03-24: As expected, the dividend is now announced, $0.52640 per share, payable on 2020-03-30.

Comment: thanks, is there any rule that ETF companies need to follow ?

Comment: No, only the ones they make in their prospects. It's considered your duty to read those before you buy them. (But who does? Me neither)

Comment: @puzzled - see my update.